# How to parse custom JTW claims in TYK Gateway config?

Tags: jwt, tyk

I want to add new headers:
x-application-id
x-application-name
x-organisation-id
x-organisation-name

if I do like this "$tyk_context.jwt_claims_client_metadata.organisation_name" it does not work.

in the logs I see: “x-organisation-name-”

Question: how can I parse an array?

My jwt is:

```
{
  "pol": "MyAPI",
  "client_metadata": {
    "application_id": "1",
    "application_name": "SuperApp",
    "organisation_id": "1",
    "organisation_name": "SuperOrg"
  },
  "iss": "http://example.com/",
  "scope": "view create",
  "gty": "client-credentials"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is currently not possible to reach nested claims using context variables. More info [here](https://ttps://community.tyk.io/t/how-to-parse-custom-jtw-claims-in-tyk-config/6623/2)